# Smartsheet API Sign in.

Tags: api, single-sign-on, smartsheet-api

Is it possible to use Smartsheet's API to sign into Smartsheet on the Web. I am thinking of creating a form-based auth that uses the API to login. Has anyone done something like this? or is this even possible with the tokens that can be produced by the API. I am aiming for a web based single sign on without using SAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what you are asking, so I'll address each question individually in hopes that it addresses your overall question:

> Is it possible to use Smartsheet's API to sign into Smartsheet on the Web?

No, you cannot create a web session using the api. For 3rd party apps, that would defeat the purpose of using OAuth2 since the whole goal with OAuth is to grant limited access to protected resources. For user-generated access tokens, it could be feasible, since those tokens have unrestricted access, but the API does not currently support that.

> I am thinking of creating a form-based auth that uses the API to login. Has anyone done something like this?

I assume you mean you will create a form to collect a user's Smartsheet credentials and use those to have an SSO experience into Smartsheet? This is technically possible, but I'd strongly discourage against it. To create an SSO experience, you'd need to retain the password in a way that allows you to POST it on behalf of the user. This means you'd store it in a 2-way encrypted state (at best), which is definitely not best practice. Again, I'd highly recommend NOT doing this.

> I am aiming for a web based single sign on without using SAML.

If you want an SSO experience into Smartsheet, you can either use SAML or Google (not truly SSO, but pretty close). There isn't an API-based approach currently.

Side note, if you want to go the other way, meaning you have a website and you want to use Smartsheet (or any OAuth2-based API for that matter) as the identity provider, you could use the 3rd Party OAuth2 flow. See the docs [here](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.opcwlo3avvxk). You could then add a "Login with Smartsheet" button to initiate that flow, much like we see everywhere on the web with "Login with Google" or "Login with Facebook".

Comment: Thanks for your response. Thing is I have put together a web "single sign on" for Salesforce by using their frontdoor.jsp. Thats why I though there would also be that possibility with Smartsheet.

Comment: Yeah, smartsheet doesn't support anything like that.  BTW, feel free to accept the answer if it answers your question.